Sobolev space as closure of smooth functions with compact support.
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\onRn}{(\R^n)}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\| #1 \|}$
I’ll be upfront:
I stumbled upon Sobolev spaces reading a paper on game theory (http://arxiv.org/abs/2411.03802). I have no background in functional analysis, so my questions may seem elementary to anyone familiar with Sobolev spaces—my apologies in advance.
Consider the Sobolev-Hilbert space $H^2\onRn = W^{2,2}\onRn$ defined as
$$H^2\onRn = \{u \in L^2\onRn: D^{\alpha}u \in L^2\onRn \text{ for all} |\alpha| \leq 2  \}$$
where $\alpha$ is a multi-index and $D^{\alpha}$ is the weak partial derivative of order $\alpha$.
$H^2\onRn$ is a Hilbert space with the inner product induced by the $L^2$ inner product
$$\langle u, v \rangle_{H^2\onRn} = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 2} \langle D^{\alpha}u, D^{\alpha}v \rangle_{L^2\onRn} $$
Let $\norm{\cdot}_{H^2\onRn}$ be induced norm (making $H^2\onRn$ into a Banach space).
Questions

The authors consider the space $\overline{C^{\infty}(\R^n)}^{\, \, \, \norm{\cdot}_{H^2\onRn}}$, which is the closure of the space of smooth functions with respect to the $H^2$ norm. Is this well defined? I do not think so, since $C^{\infty}{\onRn}$ is not a subset of $H^2\onRn$.



Assuming a typo, is the closure of the space of smooth functions with compact support with respect to the $H^2$ norm, that is $\overline{C_c^{\infty}(\R^n)}^{\, \, \, \norm{\cdot}_{H^2\onRn}}$, well defined? Namely, Is it true that $C_c^{\infty}(\R^n) \subseteq H^2\onRn$, so that the closue makes sense? I think so, e.g. by Th. 11.35 in Leoni's A First Course in Sobolev Spaces in the case $\Omega = R^n$:




Assuming the space $\overline{C_c^{\infty}(\R^n)}^{\, \, \, \norm{\cdot}_{H^2\onRn}}$ is well defined, is it equal to $H^2\onRn$ iself? If my understanding on the previous point is correct, this should be true, since if $A$ is a subset of a metric space $X$ then $A$ is dense in $X$ iff $\bar{A}^{X} = X$ (Also, I saw that there exist results about the approximation of Sobolev functions by smooth functions (e.g. section 14.2 in Leoni's book, and section 5.3 in Evans' Partial Differential Equations ), but I did not dive into the details.)


Yes, it's about functions with compact support and, yes, the closure of the smooth, compactly supported functions is equal to $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by the theorem you quote.

Keep in mind that this is not true for more general domains, e.g. $H^2(B_1(0))$ is not equal to the closure of the smooth, compactly supported functions in $B_1(0)$.


yes, you are right: $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is not a subset of $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$ (i.e. $u\equiv 1$ is in the former  but not in the latter).
Still one has that the closure of $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n) \cap H^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is equal to $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$. This is the Meyers-Serrin theorem.

yes, $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is a subset of $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

yes, the closure of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is equal to $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$. This is a standard result. I do not have a reference at hand right now.
Sometimes this is states as $H^2_0(\mathbb R^n)=H^2(\mathbb R^n)$, where $H^2_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ for $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n $ open.


In the above, one can replace $H^2$ by any Sobolev space $W^{m,p}$ with $p<\infty$.

I think 1. and 3. is even more simpler than Meyers-Serrin: Given $u \in H^2(\mathbb R)^n$ we can multiply it with a smooth cut-off function and take the convolution with a smooth mollifier and we get $u_\varepsilon \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)^n$ with $|u - u_\varepsilon|_{H^2}$ small. Meyers-Serrin is much more complicated.
